# How to compute $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{(\zeta(2k)-1)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

> How to compute $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{(\zeta(2k)-1)}$, where $\zeta(s) :=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}$ with $s>1$.

Here's my process, what am I doing wrong?:

[image]

Comment: Starting from the third line, you've got a denominator of $1/(n^2-1)$. But that blows up when $n=1$, so your resummation on the previous line can't have been done correctly.

Comment: I figured that aswell, but how do I get rid of the negative one?

Comment: One basic issue: You seem to be (correctly!) using the fact that subtracting 1 removes a term from your series. But it removes the $n=1$ term, not the $k=1$ term. Once you account for that, then you're in a position to sum the resulting series correctly.

Comment: Ah, I see. The summation index is $k$. I try to figure out how to get rid of the negative one.

Comment: You should keep it more clean by using brackets. It's really confusing in this form. I'm talking about the picture.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Infinite_series ... second formula ...

Comment: My textbook claims that the value of the sum is $0.5$, it might be a typo...

Comment: Well, i figured it out myself, i also came up with 3/4.

Answer (score 3):

Your first error is swapping the indexes $n$ and $k$ at the start of the second line, since the $n=1$ term is $\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{1^{2k}}\right)-1=\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty1\right)-1$, which is undefined. This is compounded by the lack of brackets, which makes it unclear what is inside the sum. Your second error is also in the second line, where you have

$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)^k-1\right)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{\color{red}{k=2}}^\infty\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)^k-1+\left(\frac1{\color{red}{1}^2}\right)^k\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Ignoring that the sum is undefined due to the $n=1$ term, this is *also* incorrect since you are accounting for a term in $n$ by changing the index in $k$. However, it is clear that you are trying to take out a term of the series, which is a good tactic but should be done as $\sum_{i=1}^Na_i=a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_N=\color{red}{a_1}+\sum_{\color{red}{i=2}}^Na_i$. The index you change should reflect the index you substitute.

You can mitigate these two errors by *first* dealing with the $n=1$ term before swapping the indexes.

$$\require{cancel}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^{2k}}-1\right)
&=
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\cancel{\frac{1}{1^{2k}}}+\frac{1}{2^{2k}}+\ldots\cancel{-1}\right)
\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{2k}}
\end{aligned}
$$

At which point, you could swap the indexes, use your geometric series argument from the third line and complete the proof.

$$\begin{aligned}
&=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2-1}
\end{aligned}
$$

You should try not to assume that a rearrangement is convergent without justification since it is not a given that $\sum_n$ and $\sum_k$ could be swapped or that the geometric series would even converge. You could also try to improve your notation since your $1$s look like $7$s.

Comment: Please, write $n=2$ instead of $n=1$ in the last terms. Then you can add: $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2-1} = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty (\frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n+1}) = \frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{1}{2})=\frac{3}{4}\,$ .

Comment: Indeed you can show that the sum from $n=2$ is $3/4$ with that rearrangement but that is not the only point I am making in my answer so will not change the index to $n=2$. The OP has swapped the indexes of the sums leading to the first $n=1$ term being undefined, which is one of the errors they have made in their proof.

Comment: If they argued that $\sum_k\left(\sum_{n=1}\frac1{n^{2k}}-1\right)=\sum_k\left(\sum_{n=2}\frac1{n^{2k}}\right)$ and *then* swapped the indexes, used the geometric series argument and your rearrangement then sure; I'd agree that their proof would work. But as it stands they have $\infty+3/4$

Comment: It's much better if you write down only the correct calculation instead of repeating the mistakes. The OP will see, what is wrong; you will see. ;)

Comment: @user90369 Fair point; edited my answer.

Comment: (+1) for giving the OP a simple solution ;)

Answer (score 2):

Using $~\displaystyle\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty\left(1-\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)^2\right)=\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}~$ we have: 
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^{2k}}{2k}\zeta(2k) = -\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}~,~~|x|<1$$

Differentiation and then substraction of $~\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty x^{2k-1} = \frac{x}{1-x^2}~$ and after that the limit for $~x\uparrow 1~$ gives us the result $~\displaystyle\frac{3}{4}~$.

*Hint:* $~~\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x}+\pi\cot(\pi(1-x))\right)=0$

*Note:* $~~$ But of course, using the result of e.g. *Jam*, it's easier to write

$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2-1} = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{3}{4}\,$ .